# Relationship between image of a linear transformation and its support

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Suppose I have a linear transformation $T: V \rightarrow V$.

The kernel of the transformation is the subspace spanned by the vectors $v\in V$ such that $Tv = 0$. The orthogonal complement to the kernel is called the support of $T$. Finally, the image of $T$ is the subspace spanned by vectors $Tv$ for $v\in V$.

Are the image and the support always the same if the linear transformation is from one vector space to itself? If yes, how does one show this and if not, what is the relationship between the two?

EDIT: Thanks to Ted Shifrin for the helpful comment. If $T$ is self-adjoint, then pick any $v$ from the kernel of $T$ and some $w\in V$. It holds that $0 = \langle Tv, w\rangle = \langle v, Tw\rangle$ i.e. $Tw$ is orthogonal to $v$ or $Tw = 0$. This makes it clear that the image and the support are indeed the same.

Comment: Only when $T$ is self-adjoint are these the same. (Note you are assuming $V$ has an inner product.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space (inner product space presumably), then the only relationship between the image and the support is that they necessary have the same dimension (as a consequence of the rank-nullity theorem).

Comment: Thank you - it's almost clear to me. One last thing, if $T$ is not self-adjoint, is there a simple example of a linear transformation to show the case where the kernel and the support are not the same?

Comment: $\pmatrix{0&1\\ 0&0}$